# How can I convert CachedNetworkImage to ImageProvider?

Tags: flutter

I want to show CachedNetworkImage in CircleAvatar Widget but backgroundImage parameter require ImageProvider.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If what you want is just a circle-shaped `CachedNetworkImage`, you can use `ClipOval`:

```
    ClipOval(
        child: CachedNetworkImage(
            width: 32,
            height: 32,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            imageUrl: 'BLA.jpg',
            placeholder: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 13):

Use [CachedNetworkImageProvider](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/cached_network_image/latest/cached_network_image/CachedNetworkImageProvider-class.html)

> Creates an ImageProvider which loads an image from the url, using the
>   scale. When the image fails to load errorListener is called.

Comment: How can I make placeholder with CachedNetworkImageProvider?

Comment: `ImageProvider`s don't have placeholders. It's up to the Widget to do that. Look at how `CircleAvatar` uses the provider and consider adapting it for your own use case.

Answer (score 8):

please use imageBuilder from CachedNetworkImage

```
 CachedNetworkImage(
      placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      imageUrl: imagePath,
      imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) { // you can access to imageProvider
        return CircleAvatar( // or any widget that use imageProvider like (PhotoView)
          backgroundImage: imageProvider,
        );
      },
    )
```

Comment: The property of `fit: BoxFit.contain` in CachedNetworkImage looks good!

Answer (score 3):

If your intention is to show the image inside a circular.

Use:

```
ClipRRect(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
child: CachedNetworkImage(...))
```

If you want to convert the `CachedNetworkImage` into `ImageProvider`

Use:

```
CachedNetworkImageProvider(url)
```