# Flutter CachedNetworkImageProvider does not have a loading spinner

Tags: image, caching, networking, dart, flutter

Please let me know how to enable loading spinner for flutter `CachedNetworkImageProvider`. This works fine with `CachedNetworkImage`. But the problem is `CachedNetworkImage` is not a valid image provider.

```
Container(
  width: 80.0,
  height: 80.0,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: CachedNetworkImageProvider('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/945853318273761280/0U40alJG_400x400.jpg'),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54777842/9746484

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have achieved this to some extent by using [AdvancedNetworkImage](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_advanced_networkimage) 
The issue now I am facing is rounding of top left and right corners does not work in the below code.

[image]

```
new Column(
  children: [

  Container (
    height: 250.0,
    width : double.infinity,
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top:20.0, left: 20.0, right:20.0),

    child: TransitionToImage(

    AdvancedNetworkImage(getImage(context, i), timeoutDuration: Duration(minutes: 1), useDiskCache: true),
    // placeholder: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    loadingWidget: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
    placeholder: const Icon(Icons.refresh),
    enableRefresh: true,                    
    ),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(                    

    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only( topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0), topRight: Radius.circular(10.0) ),
    ),
  ),


  Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:20.0, left: 20.0, right:20.0),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.black,
    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only( bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0), bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.0)  ),
    boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
        BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.black,
        offset: Offset(0.0, -12.0),
        blurRadius: 20.0,
        ),
    ],
    ),

    // alignment: TextAlign.left,
    child: new Text( getTitle(context, i), style: TextStyle( color: Colors.white, fontSize: 30.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.normal) ),
  ),

  ],
)
```

If anyone know the issue with rounding corners, please comment.

Comment: AdvancedNetworkImage package is now discontinued.

Comment: This is not proper answer. Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64394772/3197387

Answer (score 5):

You can use imageBuilder property of CachedNetworkImage

```
CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: 'yourURL',
    imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
       image: DecorationImage(
         image: imageProvider,
         fit: BoxFit.cover,
       ),
    ),
),
```

This way you can decorate your CachedNetworkImage like a Container

Answer (score 3):

A little late but I followed this approach

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/fading-in-images

Using `Stack`, `Padding`, and the `Container` should do it. The bad thing here is the `CircularProgressIndicator` running in the background but it's invisible for the user. The Image should be bigger than the `CircularProgressIndicator`.

An example here

```
Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
         Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 15),
                 child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
         ),
         Container(
              width: 80.0,
              height: 80.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
               'https://www.seti.org/sites/default/files/styles/original/public/2019-09/Zork%20alien%20head%20PPR.jpg?itok=T7eTYzCZ'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

The purpose of the Padding is to be behind the Image, no matter where it is.
For small images like this I think it is better the `FadeInImage`

```
FadeInImage(image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(url),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            placeholder: MemoryImage(kTransparentImage),
            )
```