Stuck UI during Image fetching in flutter
Widget _buildNewsCard(Map<String, dynamic> article) {
  return Card(
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            article['title'],
            maxLines: 2,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  article['description'] ?? '',
                  maxLines: 2,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                if (article['urlToImage'] != null)
                  FadeInImage(
                    placeholder: AssetImage('assets/images/logo.png'), // Placeholder image
                    image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(article['urlToImage']),
                    width: 100, // Adjust the width as needed
                    height: 100, // Adjust the height as needed
                    fit: BoxFit.cover, // Image fit
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}

I am creating a news UI. It working fine if i don't show the image(which i am getting from the api) but if i show the image it going to stuck. i have tried but not finding any solutions.

Can you describe more or give the visual about what (image) stuck you are experiencing

this article may give u some hints, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53470270/flutter-cachednetworkimageprovider-does-not-have-a-loading-spinner

I have designed a UI to show the news details. Problems is when i adding image in the UI the ui is not scrolling. it stuck and not working

could you include the ui that you try to achieve?
